# Deleting part of href using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have few bookmarks in the CMS:

```
 <li><a href="#online">Chat Online</a> </li>
 <li><a href="#termsOfService">Terms of Service</a> </li>
```

But CMS is adding some url before # in the link which breaks my functionality.
Is there any way to delete everything before # in a link using **Jquery**.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

You could write a regular expression to remove everything before the hash in the href attribute. I'd suggest doing it on the server-side, but if you must use jQuery it might look something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/E67K3/):

```
$('li a').each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href').replace(/.*(#.*)$/, "$1");
    $(this).attr('href', href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These elements have an id? If they do, you could do something like this, being XXX the internal id of each element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var href = $('#XXX').attr('href');
    href = href.split('#')[1]; 
    $('#XXX').attr('href', href);
});
```

If you wish to apply this to every anchor in you page, then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        href = href.split('#')[1]; 
        $(this).attr('href', href);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zk556/)**

```
$(function(){
    $("a").each(function(){
        if(this.href && (this.href.indexOf("#") != -1)){
           this.href = this.href.split("#")[1];
        }
    });
});
```